# Count rows of each feature class listed in table with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I have a table in a geodatabase: `tableA`

A column in that table lists a couple of feature classes that are in the geodatabase.

I want to make a loop on each name, count the number of rows in the attribute table of each feature class and store this value in a column of 'tableA'.

Here is what I've tried:

```
arcpy.env.workspace =r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\geodatabase\geoA.gdb'
dataset = arcpy.ListTables("tableA") #the table needed is 'tableA'
arcpy.AddField_management("tableA", "rows_count", "LONG") #create field with the count_rows
for i in dataset:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("tableA",["file_name","rows_count"]) as cur: #the fields that needed
        for row in cur:
            try:
                nrow = arcpy.GetCount_management (row[0]) #count each layer's rows
                row[1].setValue('rows_count', nrow) #fill the column with the values found
                cur.updateRow(row) #apply changes        
            except arcpy.ExecuteError as e:                     
                print(e)
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setValue'

In the result, the `rows_count` is null for all rows at the creation of the field.

What can be done here?

How the table looks:

```
file_name  rows_count
file1       null
file2       null
file3 ...   null
```

Question:

In the main table, how to count the number of rows for each of these files and add store this vlue in a column ?

**UPDATE**

Wanted output

```
tableA

file_name  rows_count
file1         0
file2         12
file3         1
...
```

Where `file1,file2, etc` are actual feture classes in the `gdb` and `rows_count` are the number of rows in each file.

Comment: You are trying to perform GetCount() on one particular field ("filename") in a single row in the table rather than the whole table. The input should be a layer or feature class.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-count.htm

Comment: each row exists as a feature layer as well in the same gdb

Comment: I don't have access to ArcGIS right now but I think you should be calling `GetCount()` on `i` rather than the indexed field in your cursor (`row[0]`).

Comment: the counting works ok.So this doesn't have to change. The problem is to put the numbers in the new column.

Comment: Is the field being successfully added to "TableA"? The UpdateCursor has no reference to it.

Comment: No It doesn't. So you suggest to just `i` in the getcount?And how it will know which field to count without specifying the field?

Comment: You have 2 issues here - the field is not being added, but I think it stems from further back - and I think you are misinterpreting what `GetCount()` does.

Have you checked what is stored in your `dataset` variable? I would think it's going to be a list with a single item based on line 2.

In which case your `for i in dataset:` loop is redundant. 

I would suggest explicitly assigning the path of the table to your `dataset` variable with `dataset = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\geodatabase\geoA.gdb\tableA`

You should then be able to use `dataset` as the input for `'AddField_management()'`.

Comment: I think the first for is redundant, true. In the new field it doesn't store anything but if I put a print for `nrow` it prints exactly what I want which is the rows of each feature layer in the row of the field in the table.

Comment: My apologies, I see what your GetCount() is doing now. So it's just making sure  the field is successfully added...

Comment: You've got this hybrid DataAccess/old-style cursor usage thing happening. Data Access cursors use arrays, so the error message is entirely correct -- there is no SetValue request. Writing your own GetCount function is fine, but your really ought to name it differently from the arcpy request or else include it in your code snippet.

Comment: I haven't made any function.What are you talking about?

Comment: @MattNeedle What do you mean?Your suggestion isn't applicable in the end?

Comment: `row[1]` is returning a `NoneType` which implies the second item in the fields list that you pass to `UpdateCursor` doesn't exist. Are you sure the field is being added successfully to "tableA"?

Comment: yes it is there.It's just empty.The part where try to populate that field is where the error emerges.

Comment: Then you need to include your `import` statements, for clarity, and use `arcpy.GetCount_management` properly (it returns an array of strings, not a single integer), so you have two errors on successive lines.

Comment: Please give an example of your desired output, because your script is unclear. 1) The number of row is a property so it can be easily accessible by code or read in ArcMap when you open the table2). Why making a new COLUMN" to store the number of rows; if you loop on a set of feature (which you don't presently), it would be more efficient to store each count in a row (one table with fc_name and FC_countrow). 3) If you need to add one row per dataset, use insertCursor and not updateCursor, but maybe you have the names of the dataset already in tableA. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error comes from the fact that arcpy.da returns a cursor with no method setValue. It returns a list at each iteration, that you can manipulate like a list. 'row' will contain the values of the fields selected in the cursor inside a list. Just use indice to read and write those field values (row[index] = new_value_for_the_field_at_the_specified_index).

the use of GetCount() should also be modified, because GetCount doesn't return a number but it returns an object that contains a string (don't ask me why).

and the loop on dataset is useless because you have a single table to fill.

```
arcpy.env.workspace =r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\geodatabase\geoA.gdb'
arcpy.AddField_management("tableA", "rows_count", "LONG") #create field with the count_rows
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("tableA",["file_name","rows_count"]) as cur: #the fields that needed
    for row in cur: #for each row
        try:
            #GetCount will return a "result object", the count itself is the first element of the result of getCount() 
            row[1] = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(row[0])[0]) #reads the name of feature class (check that paths are correct)
            cur.updateRow(row) #apply changes        
        except arcpy.ExecuteError as e:                     
            print(e)
```

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: it now says: TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: The dataset loop is indeed useless but what is the way to actually populate the field?

Comment: What is your ArcMap version ?

Comment: 10.6 is the version

Comment: I've tested with 10.6 and it works for me.

Comment: maybe you should try with the full paths

Comment: The only different thing is that instead of the filenames being :file1,file2,file3, are W_E_001,W_E_002,W_E_003.

Comment: did you write the GetCount(...) exactly like me ?

Comment: yes exactly.it said error with the tuple as the comment above.the error is caused from the GetCount line.How do you suggest about the full path process?

Comment: ok worked great. I hadn't removed the initial for loop.I thought it was redundant not an actual problem.Thanks. can you explain what you do with in the getcount line?